# Empty scroll view and loading photos asynchronously

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

How can I init an empty scroll view with a certain number of pages (depending of number of photos I need to show), while an NSOperationQueue is downloading photos one by one from a web service ?

I would like to show an UIActivityIndicatorView on each page of the scroll view, and when one of my photo is downloaded, show it on the corresponding page.

It seems there is no example on the Web...

Answer (score 0):

The following 3 WWDC videos will help.

Session 105 - Polishing Your App WWDC 2011
Session 125 - UITableView Changes, Tips, Tricks WWDC 2011
UITableView Talk (don't recall the # or title) from WWDC 2010

Your question has no easy answer. But the general approach;

- create and init the scrollview as if you had the photos (i.e. set its contentSize to match the eventual photo count)
- download the photos in the background as you suggest
- as the photos come in use performSelector:onMainThread: method variants to send a message to one of your controllers on the main thread that an image is ready for display
- add a UIImageView to the correct page in the scroll view (WWDC 2010 Scroll View talk will help here)

good luck

Comment: Thank you, I will watch videos. It seems that's my problem isn't for beginner like me.

Comment: sure, if you are brand new to programming this is a big program, start with displaying your name or something similar then work up to displaying local photos, then on to downloading. good luck

Comment: I'm not brand new to programming at all, but with Cocoa, i've just started few months ago. My problem is about lazy loading with the scroll view...

Comment: cool, suggestion still stands, start with something small to get started, then build to your lazy loading scroll view, the videos from WWDC will help